# HTML Label "For" Value

Tags: html, forms

I have a label tag that I am trying to link to an input type checkbox tag.  I have multiple labels and multiple checkbox inputs, and they all have the same id and the same name, but different values.  Can someone instruct me as how to construct a label that links to a value rather than an id?  So this:

```
<label for="8994"></label>
```

Would link to:

```
<input id="member_ids_" name="member_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="8994">
```

Or is this not possible?

Comment: `they all have the same id` that's the problem they shouldn't have the same id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The label's `for` attribute must match the ID of the `<input>` element it refers to. In your case it would be something like:

```
<label for="member_id_8994"></label>
<input id="member_id_8994" name="member_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="8994">
```

Answer (score 2):

The 'for' for the form element must match with the ID of the same form element.

```
<label for="id_1"></label>
<input id="id_1" name="member_ids[1]" type="checkbox" value="8994">

<label for="id_2"></label>
<input id="id_2" name="member_ids[2]" type="checkbox" value="8994">

<label for="id_3"></label>
<input id="id_3" name="member_ids[3]" type="checkbox" value="8994">

<label for="id_3"></label>
<input id="id_3" name="member_ids[4]" type="checkbox" value="8994">
```

Answer (score 1):

Your DOM elements ***must*** have different IDs.
Even if each ID is just set to whatever that value is...  ...or whatever.

They can not have the same ID.

Once you've got that out of the way, setting `for` on a label becomes really simple.

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery solution that probably doesn't work.

```
 $(function() {
    ModifyLabels({target: $('input')});
    $('input').change(ModifyLabels);
 });

function ModifyLabels(eventObject) {
    var inputs = $(eventObject.target);
    input.each(function(i, input) {
         $('label').each(function(i, label) {
             if ($(label).attr('for') == $(input).val()) {
                $(input).attr('id', $(input).val());
             }
         });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if that is possible. Label's    for are tied to the id attribute of inputs. One way to do achieve your objective maybe through javascript, knockout's declarative bindings for instance.

check it our here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html

Something along this line:

```
<label data-bind="click: myInput"></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="hello">

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myInput= {
        //implement the function to bind the label to the input#hello here
        }
    };
</script>
```

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html